# Count which mail has the highest number occurs in every segment of string using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string

From the below string, I want to count which email has the highest number occurs in every segment of string.

**Here's my String:**

```
String strA = "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,az@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,";
```

**Output that I want to achieve: 4,3,3**

**Explanation about my output:**

In the first segment- "ax@gmail.com" is 4 times and it's occurs highest among other email.

In the second segment- "az@gmail.com" is 3 times and it's occurs highest among other email.

In the third segment- "ax@gmail.com and ay@gmail.com" both are occurs 3 times, so I want to count 3.

**Currently I am able to count number of unique email are available in every segment of string.**

**Here's my Code:**

```
String strA = "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,az@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,";
String[] lines = strA.split("\n");
List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    counts.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(","))).size());
}
System.out.println(counts);  // [3, 3, 2]
```

**But how to reach my goal, Output: 4,3,3**

Please help me. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, how about the following suggestion:

```
    String strA = "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,az@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,";
    String[] lines = strA.split("\n");

    List<HashMap<String, Integer>> segments = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String line: lines){
        HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
        segments.add(counts);
        String[] emails = line.split(",");
        for(String email : emails){
            Integer emailCount = counts.containsKey(email) ? counts.get(email) + 1 : 1;

            counts.put(email, emailCount);
        }
    }
    segments.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
{ax@gmail.com=4, ay@gmail.com=3, az@gmail.com=3}
{ax@gmail.com=2, ay@gmail.com=2, az@gmail.com=3}
{ax@gmail.com=3, ay@gmail.com=3}
```

EDIT:
to get the desired output you can replace the last line with this one:

```
    segments.forEach(segment -> {
       segment.forEach((key, val) -> {
           System.out.print(val + " ");
       });
        System.out.println();
    });
```

2  EDIT:

After I have now understood the task here is an update :D :

```
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String strA = "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,az@gmail.com,az@gmail.com," + '\n' +
            "ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,ax@gmail.com,ay@gmail.com,";
    String[] lines = strA.split("\n");
    System.out.print("[");
    for(String line: lines){

        Integer count = getMaxCountForSegment(line.split(","));
        System.out.print(count + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}

public static Integer getMaxCountForSegment(String[] emails){
    HashMap<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    for(String email : emails){
       Integer emailCount = counts.containsKey(email) ? counts.get(email) + 1 : 1;
        counts.put(email, emailCount);
    }
    return counts.values().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf)).get();
}
```

Output:

```
[4, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.But i want to print only 4,3,3 in my output console. How to print this? I cant get output from this "segments.forEach(System.out::println);". @H4x9r

Comment: Which java version do you use, can be of course that lambdas are not yet available. 
In the end you have a list of hashmaps each hashmap has as key the email and as value the number of emails per segment. 
Accordingly you can replace the last line with: 
     segments.forEach(segment -> {
           segment.forEach((key, val) -> {
               System.out.print(val + " ");
           });
            System.out.println();
        });

Comment: How i get only 4,3,3 outside in "segments.forEach(segment -> {...});" this snippet?Because, It will provide output repeatedly?Also i cant access "val" outside from this snippet.@H4x9r

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. Do you want to get a list or an array back? Do you want the result for only one segment or for all at the same time?

Comment: Please look my question code,how i print ("System.out.println(counts);  // [3, 3, 2]") unique email number in every segment. Similarly, I want to print the count number which email has the highest number occurs in every segment of string. So, the output i want to achieve like this,"("System.out.println(counts);  // [4, 3, 3]")".Hope now you clear.@H4x9r

Comment: ah lol, yes sorrz that i am so slow on the uptake,  now it should work

Comment: I'm really sorry that, I can't explain my problem to you. Look at the first segment of my string, there ax=4 and ay=3,az=3 times repeat, so i store only 4(max repeat) from here. Now look second segment of string, there ax=2,ay=2 and az=3 times repeat, so i store only 3(max repeat) from here. Now look third segment of string, ax=3,ay=3,az=3 times repeat, so i store 3 from here because all of the(ax, ay, az) are same occuring value. So, i want to print to all stored value(4,3,3) in system.out.println.@H4x9r

Comment: yeah that is exactly what i did , you can call my method getMaxCountForSegment, this will return you the max occurence of an email. For the first segment the return value would be 4 , for the second 3 and for the last also 3. How you will print these returned values is up to you....

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `HashMap`.
The idea is to declare an `HashMap<String, Integer>`. Where the `String` key is an email and the `Integer` value is the occurence of this email.

- First you split your String in lines.
- Then you iterate through each line :

  1. You instantiate a `HashMap<String, Integer>`. It will count the occurence of each mail
  2. You split the line by calling `line.split(",");`. By this, you can get each email. Then you iterate through :

     - if the mail is in the `HashMap`, you increment the value.
     - Else you put the mail with a value of 0.
  3. After the loop, you extract the maximum value stored in the `HashMap`. (you can iterate an `HashMap` by calling `yourHashMap.entrySet()`. This method return an array of `EntrySet`).

Here is the logic. I don't put any code to let you write it alone. But if you block on anything, tell me I will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Java Stream in those use cases:

```
List<Long> maxOccurrencesInSegments = Arrays.stream(strA.split("\n"))
        .mapToLong(segmentStr ->
                Arrays.stream(segmentStr.split(","))
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                        .entrySet().stream()
                        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                        .get()
        )
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(maxOccurrencesInSegments);
```

Output:

```
[4, 3, 3]
```